# Name of parent page in menu

Tags: wordpress

somone please know a plugin or php function in wordpress to make  or give the name of current and the parent page like that :

In Product page:

```
Home (Parent page) >> User(child page) >> Product (current page) >>...
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called breadcrumbs. Give that a search.